# My code is not working for insert condition?

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I am trying to make trigger on opportunity to get price books name in pricebook2id field of opportunity? Can you help me out in this?

```
trigger Oppor on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){

 List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

 Set<Id> setId=new Set<Id>();

   for(Opportunity o:Trigger.new)
        {
            setId.add(o.AccountId);
        }

   system.debug(setId);

 oppList = [Select Id, Name, Opportunity.Account.Name, 
Opportunity.Account.BillingCity from Opportunity where AccountId=: setId ];

 system.debug(oppList);

 List<Pricebook2> PB=new List<Pricebook2>();

 PB =[select id from Pricebook2 where Name =:'Rick' ];

  for(pricebook2 pc : PB)
        {

  for(Opportunity Op : oppList)
            {

     for(Opportunity Opp : trigger.new)
                {

      if(Op.Account.BillingCity == 'Slo')
                    {

         Opp.Pricebook2Id = pc.Id;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PB =[select id from Pricebook2 where Name =:'Rick' ];

for(pricebook2 pc : PB)
    {

for(Opportunity Op : oppList)
        {

 for(Opportunity Opp : trigger.new)
            {

  if(Op.Account.BillingCity == 'Slo')
                {

     Opp.Pricebook2Id = pc.Id;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Sorry I'm not understanding this code.  You are looping through all the price books that get returned, then looping through all the opportunities that were returned via your query and then looping through all the opportunities in your query and if the current opportunity in your query list has a specific billing city you are then updating all the records in your trigger to the current price book value.  There seems to be no logic to this.  You don't seem to care that your opportunity returned in the query is the same one that you are updating as part of the trigger.

Imagine this your price book list contains 2 records, your query of opps contains 3 records all with "Slo" as the city and your trigger contains 1 record.

So your loop starts with the first price book,
Then it loops through all 3 records from your trigger and since they all have slo as the city it changes the 1 trigger record 3 times to the first pricebook.  Then it will start the second price book record.  It will again go through all 3 queried opps and again update the 1 trigger record 3 times to the second price book id.

I'm not sure what your intention is.  If you assume there is only one pricebook entry with a name rick and then you want to find out if the current trigger record has an account with 'Slo' then you need to match up the queried record with the correct trigger record before you update.

If you only have one price book record and you want to determine if the trigger record account is 'slo' do this.

Edit: Fixing some typeos in the code example

```
Map<id, Account> mapAccounts = new map<id,Account> ([Select id, BillingCity from 
Account where id in: setId]);

PB =[select id from Pricebook2 where Name =:'Rick' ]; //(Assume only 1)

for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new)
{
   if(mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId).BillingCity == 'Slo')
   {
      opp.Pricebook2Id =PB[0].ID;
   }
}
```